# parse lazy load result table(json)

Tags: asp.net, html-parsing

i try to parse this link : http://agent.bronni.ru/Result.aspx?id=c7a6a33a-174e-426d-b127-828ee612c36e&account=27178&page=1&pageSize=50&mr=true

but i can t get the result table because as i see in fiddler there are lazyloading method with json result.

My code is :

HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load("http://agent.bronni.ru/Result.aspx?id=c7a6a33a-174e-426d-b127-828ee612c36e&account=27178&page=1&pageSize=50&mr=true");

```
    // Get all tables in the document
    HtmlNodeCollection tables = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table");

    // Iterate all rows in the first table
    HtmlNodeCollection rows = tables[0].SelectNodes(".//tr");

    var data = rows.Skip(1).ToList().Take(10).ToList().Select(x => new TableRow()
    {
        Price = x.SelectNodes(".//td").ToList()[4].InnerText,
        Operator = x.SelectNodes(".//td").ToList()[15].InnerText,
        DepartureDate = x.SelectNodes(".//td").ToList()[6].InnerText,
        DestinationRegion = x.SelectNodes(".//td").ToList()[7].InnerText
    }).ToList();
```

**UPDATE**
Second site :
Code

```
 WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.Headers.Add("Referer", "http://sletat.ru/");//MUST BE THIS HEADER
        string result = wc.DownloadString("http://module.sletat.ru/Main.svc/GetTours?cityFromId=832&countryId=35&cities=&meals=&stars=&hotels=&s_adults=1&s_kids=0&s_kids_ages=&s_nightsMin=6&s_nightsMax=16&s_priceMin=0&s_priceMax=&currencyAlias=RUB&s_departFrom=25%2F06%2F2012&s_departTo=31%2F07%2F2012&visibleOperators=&s_hotelIsNotInStop=true&s_hasTickets=true&s_ticketsIncluded=true&debug=0&filter=0&f_to_id=&requestId=19198631&pageSize=20&pageNumber=1&updateResult=1&includeDescriptions=1&includeOilTaxesAndVisa=1&userId=&jskey=1&callback=_jqjsp&_1340633427022=");
        result = result.Substring(result.IndexOf("{"), result.LastIndexOf("}") - result.IndexOf("{") + 1);
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        dynamic json = js.DeserializeObject(result);
        var prices = json["GetToursResult"]["Data"]["aaData"] as object[];
        // var operators = ((object[])json["result"]["prices"]).Cast<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        var temp = prices.ToList().Take(20).Select(x => new TableRow
        {
            Operator = (x as object[])[40].ToString(),
            //Price = x["operatorPrice"].ToString(),
            //DepartureDate = x["checkinDate"].ToString(),
            //DestinationRegion = ((Dictionary<string, object>)x["country"])["englishName"].ToString()
        }).ToList();

        string str = "";

        foreach (var tableRow in temp)
        {
            str += tableRow.Operator + "<br />";
        }
        Response.Write(str);
```

In this way i try all works ok but the problem is that this link works for roughly 30minutes and then i need to put other link again.Is any way to fix this?(only the second site has it)
THanks again,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is really coming from here:

http://beta.remote.bronni.ru/LazyLoading.ashx/getResult?jsonp=jQuery17207647891761735082_1340131755603&id=c7a6a33a-174e-426d-b127-828ee612c36e&page=3&pageSize=50&_=1340131756631

With the exception that the `page=#` and `pageSize=#` can be adjusted dynamically.

So instead of parsing HTML, you could just get the JSON data from the URL and parse it. For example:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
string result =wc.DownloadString("http://beta.remote.bronni.ru/LazyLoading.ashx/getResult?jsonp=jQuery17207647891761735082_1340131755603&id=c7a6a33a-174e-426d-b127-828ee612c36e&page=1&pageSize=1000&_=1340131756631");
result = result.Substring(result.IndexOf("{"),result.LastIndexOf("}")-result.IndexOf("{")+1);
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
dynamic json =  js.DeserializeObject(result);
var prices = ((object[])json["result"]["prices"]).Cast<Dictionary<string,object>>();
var data = from p in prices 
           select new
{
  OperatorID = p["operatorID"],
  Price = p["operatorPrice"],
  Country = ((Dictionary<string,object>)p["country"])["englishName"],
  CheckinDate = p["checkinDate"]
};

Console.WriteLine(data);
```

On my LinqPad program, produces something like:

```
OperatorID Price Country CheckinDate 
0          1,27  Greece  2012-06-28 
0          55,90 Greece  2012-06-28 
0          67,34 Greece  2012-06-28
```

And many more rows, depending on how much you ask for...

**Note**: the reason for the `result = result.Substring(result.IndexOf("{"),result.LastIndexOf("}")-result.IndexOf("{")+1);` line is that the jsonp result has this garbage in the beginning:

```
jQuery17207647891761735082_1340131755603({"
```

Ending with `})` which makes the JavascriptSerializer choke when it tries to parse it; hence the need to remove it.

**Update:**

Interestingly, the ASHX handler that returns the data seems to require a `Referer` Header in the request; otherwise, the response will not include the operator information. The Referer required cannot be anything you want, it seems that it's actually looking for `http://agent.bronni.ru` in particular.

Basically, all you need to do is the following:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers.Add("Referer","http://agent.bronni.ru");//MUST BE THIS HEADER
string result =wc.DownloadString("http://beta.remote.bronni.ru/LazyLoading.ashx/getResult?jsonp=jQuery17207647891761735082_1340131755603&id=c7a6a33a-174e-426d-b127-828ee612c36e&page=1&pageSize=1000&_=1340131756631");
result = result.Substring(result.IndexOf("{"),result.LastIndexOf("}")-result.IndexOf("{")+1);
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
dynamic json =  js.DeserializeObject(result);
var prices = ((object[])json["result"]["prices"]).Cast<Dictionary<string,object>>();
var data = from p in prices 
           select new
{
  OperatorID = p["operatorID"],
  Price = p["operatorPrice"],
  Country = ((Dictionary<string,object>)p["country"])["englishName"],
  Hotel = ((Dictionary<string,object>)p["hotel"])["englishName"],
  Operator = ((Dictionary<string,object>)p["operator"])["englishName"],//OPERATOR
  CheckinDate = p["checkinDate"]
};

OperatorID Price Country Hotel                           Operator          CheckinDate 
19681      1,27  Greece  Julia Hotel                     Mouzenidis Travel 2012-06-28 
19681      1,27  Greece  Forest Park                     Mouzenidis Travel 2012-06-28 
19681      1,27  Greece  Kassandra Mare (ï-îâ Êàññàíäðà) Mouzenidis Travel 2012-06-28
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I decided to compare the performance of the out-of-the-box Javascriptserializer vs [JSON.NET serializer](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) and in all my tests with different record sizes (50,1000,3000) JSON.NET was at least twice faster than the Javascriptserializer and in some cases even 10 times faster on smaller record-sets.

If you decide to use the JSON.NET library, here's the code that will get you the same results as above code:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers.Add("Referer","http://agent.bronni.ru");
string result =wc.DownloadString("http://beta.remote.bronni.ru/LazyLoading.ashx/getResult?jsonp=jQuery17207647891761735082_1340131755603&id=c7a6a33a-174e-426d-b127-828ee612c36e&page=1&pageSize=50&_=1340131756631");
result = result.Substring(result.IndexOf("{"),result.LastIndexOf("}")-result.IndexOf("{")+1);
JObject o = JObject.Parse(result);
var data = from x in o["result"]["prices"]
select new
 {
  OperatorID = x["operatorID"],
  Price = x["operatorPrice"],
  Country = x["country"]["englishName"],
  Hotel = x["hotel"]["englishName"],
  Operator = x["operator"]["englishName"],
  CheckinDate = x["checkinDate"]
};

Console.WriteLine(data);
```

Comment: Yes of course :), somethink last, can i use the same method for the http://sletat.ru/ site? i think that it produces jsp result but i cannot find a working link

Comment: @gunner yes, you can. The data is coming from: http://module.sletat.ru/Main.svc/GetTours?cityFromId=832&countryId=40&cities=&meals=&stars=&hotels=&s_adults=3&s_kids=3&s_kids_ages=2%2C2%2C2&s_nightsMin=6&s_nightsMax=16&s_priceMin=0&s_priceMax=&currencyAlias=RUB&s_departFrom=22%2F06%2F2012&s_departTo=30%2F06%2F2012&visibleOperators=&s_hotelIsNotInStop=true&s_hasTickets=true&s_ticketsIncluded=true&debug=0&filter=0&f_to_id=&requestId=18750133&pageSize=20&pageNumber=1&updateResult=1&includeDescriptions=1&includeOilTaxesAndVisa=1&userId=&jskey=1&callback=_jqjsp&_1340373242614=

Comment: BUT you must include the referer header in the request. This time, this one works `wc.Headers.Add("Referer","http://sletat.ru/search.aspx");` and then the same thing I did on my above answer. The data is coming back mostly in Russian and I can't make sense out of most of it.

Comment: yes i understand, i did it all is ok but i cannot understand somethink maybe "stupid". I get the refferer and the link of data from fiddler.but this returns an error.The same happens with the link you gave me.When i click on the link you send me it works but when i copy-paste this link from the browser its returns"_jqjsp({"GetToursResult":{"Data":null,"ErrorMessage":"а баОаЖаАаЛаЕаНаИб, ааАб аБбаАбаЗаЕб аНаЕ........"

Comment: Precisely, it returns an error when you do it from the browser because by clicking on the link directly, the browser will not add the referer header (if you copy/paste the address) or it will put stackoverflow.com as the referer if you click on the link from here and apparently, those people only return data of they see the referer header being the website I mentioned above. It must be some sort of "security mechanism" that they use to make sure only certain websites can consume their data. Obviously that is flawed because you can fake the referer easily programmatically or with other tools.

Comment: I parse it successfully but other problem appears.I edit my first post and explain what happen.Thanks